# plotly python plot method launch browser

Tags: python, plotly

my problem is that the plotly python plot method

```
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='box-plot')
```

automatically launch the web browser, is it possible to prevent this behaviour ?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plotly for Python can be configured to render locally inside Jupyter (IPython) notebooks, locally inside your web browser, or remotely in your online Plotly account.

Offline mode will save an HTML file locally and open it inside your web browser.

[plot()](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/plotly/plotly/plotly.py#L178-L211) takes options:

> auto_open (default=True) -- Toggle browser options
>    * True: open this plot in a new browser tab
>    * False: do not open plot in the browser, but do return the unique

```
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='box-plot', auto_open=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `py.iplot`

```
plot_url = py.iplot(fig, filename='box-plot')
```

I had it this way and wanted it to actually show me the graph. So then I took away the 'i' to match your example and it worked :P

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on this. `import plotly.plotly as py` will not work anymore.
`plotly.plotly` is deprecated.

Need to install **chart_studio**

```
python2 -m pip install chart-studio
```

This will change into

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
```